# Automatically list contents of directory when changing to it

Tags: bash, bashrc, bash-alias

I am a huge fan of the ~/.bash_aliases file and I am trying to get the `cd` command to automatically list the contents of a directory when I change to it.

In my .bash_aliases file, I put `alias cd='cd $1 && ls .'`, saved the file, and then sourced the file to load it. Now, when I run `cd /`, I get the expected output, but my directory doesn't change.. I stay in my home directory.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot really do this with an alias because aliases don't use command line arguments.

You can do this with a shell function and the built-in command called, `command`.  The `command` command tells the shell to only use the built-in version of the `cd` command, not the function.  This is necessary to avoid recursion in the function:

```
cd() {
    command cd "$1" && ls
}
```